# changing to a new computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK, so I have been working through the ruby on rails tutorial by Hartl. I've begun the demo_app. I want to change computers. I downloaded ruby and ruby on rails to my new windows 8 machine. I then copied the folder with all my ruby on rails apps from my old computer to my new one. I thought everything would just work. But, no! I had to run bundle install before I could even start the rails server from within the sample_app. After that things seem to work. But I don't know why I had to do that. Can anyone explain?

Now, I'm not sure what will happen if I install github and heroku on the new machine. I think I already have a new ssh key for one thing. And so I have no idea if I do download both of those if I just continue with my development of the demo_app or if everything is going to be screwed up. Any advice would be appreciated. Yes, I'll read the git book, but I was hoping I could get going with my rails stuff in the meantime if there is some easy way to make the transition to the new machine. Or should I just stick to the old machine until I've learned a lot more about git?

Answer (score 1):

Gems are installed in your default system location for gems, not in your projects. You have copied your project folder but not the gems, that is why you have to `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 1):

What bundle install does is it installs the required gems by your application to your computer. So naturally if you change the machine, gems that installed to your previous computer is not there in your new machine. That is why you have to run bundle install again.

if you want to install your gems inside the project directory (so that if you change the machines it will not effect you) do the following

bundle install

[check this out for more info](http://madebynathan.com/2011/09/02/dont-use-bundle-install-gem/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

After installing Rails you're halfway there.
Like the other answers say you need a `bundle install`.
The next step (I would suggest) is the database-server. But you said your app is already working (?). At this point you should be able starting your web using a server like Webrick.

I think the easies way to set up Git, is installing git, set it up (like email and name and this stuff) and then cloning the repository to your new pc (with `git clone ...`). Of course you can add your new Ssh-key to Github, to have easier accces to GitHub.

I can't tell you so much about heroku because I've never used it. But if you've set up your deployment it should work like before, because (I guess) it also gets the code from github.